# double variables implementation and different outputs

Tags: java

I would like to know why there are 2 different outputs from:

```
double a = 88.0;
System.out.println(a + 10); // 98.0
double result = 88.0;
System.out.println("The result is " + result + 10); // The result is 88.010
```

Answer (score 5):

When you evaluate `"the result is " + result + 10`
you are evaluating `String + double + int`.

When this is executed, the `double` is first added to the string, creating another string, and then the `int` is added to that string, giving another string.

So you get:

```
"the result is " + result + 10
"the result is 88.0" + 10
"the result is 88.010"
```

This is different from

```
"the result is " + (result+10)
```

which would give

```
"the result is 98.0"
```

Answer (score -2):

If you use `System.out.println()` the items you put inside are automaticly casted into `String`. The plus is used to add the seperate Strings together.

If you want to do a math operation use the variables inside parenthesises.

So your code shold look like this:

```
System.out.println("the result is " + (result + 10));
```

Comment: Your first paragraph is not quite correct. Look at the first example: In `System.out.println(a + 10);` the plus sign is clearly not used to add the _Strings_ `"a"` and `"10"` together; it adds the _values_. You are right for the second case.